# Android app crashes after trying to open SettingsFragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment

I'm trying to rewrite app, written in Java in 2015 into Kotlin, but found a problem,that getFramgentManager is deprecated

***Code in Java:***

**SettingsActivity**

```java
import ...

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();

    }

}
```

**SettingsFragment**

```java
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        Preference pref = findPreference(key);

        if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
            pref.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
        }

    }

}
```

***And in Kotlin***

```
class SettingsActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }
        // Display the fragment as the main content.


        val fm : FragmentManager = FragmentActivity().supportFragmentManager
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {
        val pref = findPreference<Preference>(key)

        if (pref is ListPreference) {
            pref.setSummary(pref.entry)
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes on string `.commit`. What shall I do to fix it? I tried lots of instructions from StackOverflow, but nothing is working
And I can't do just `FragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragment())
            .commit()` , because FragmentManager is abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you must be getting the following exception or similar one.

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

It means you must not create the instance of activity from client side.

If there is not specific requirement, please extend your activity from `AppCompatActivity()`

I did a bit refactoring in your code. The following code should work.

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, SettingsFragment()).commit()

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> val fm : FragmentManager = FragmentActivity().supportFragmentManager
> ```

Lose the `FragmentActivity()` constructor call here and just access `supportFragmentManager` in your current activity that should extend `FragmentActivity` or either directly or indirectly.

You should not instantiate activities yourself.